# C Segfaults when trying to free memory that no longer needs to be used

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

I am working on a circular buffer program in C. The buffer has to be able to expand and shrink depending on certain conditions that are checked each time the buffer is updated with a new quote (the buffer contains stock quotes). However, when I try to expand the buffer and free the old (smaller) buffer, I get "invalid next size" errors from gilbc.

My expand function is as follows:

```
cbuf* expandBuffer(cbuf *cb_ptr){


    int newSize;
    newSize = (cb_ptr->maxSize * 2) -1;
    cbuf *tempBuffer = malloc(sizeof(cbuf) + newSize * sizeof(quote));
    tempBuffer ->maxSize = cb_ptr->maxSize * 2;
    tempBuffer ->start = cb_ptr->start;
    tempBuffer ->end = cb_ptr->end;
    tempBuffer ->freeSlots = tempBuffer->maxSize - cb_ptr->maxSize;

    int x;
    int counter;
    counter = 0;

    for(x = cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->maxSize; x ++){

        tempBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].time = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time;
        tempBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].rate = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate;
        counter ++;
    }
    int y;
    for(y = 0; y < cb_ptr->start; y ++){

        tempBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].time = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].time;
        tempBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].rate = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].rate;
        counter++;
    }

    tempBuffer->start = cb_ptr->maxSize;
    tempBuffer->end = 0;
    free(cb_ptr);
    return tempBuffer;

}
```

and my update function is as follows:

```
void cbuf_update(cbuf *cb_ptr, unsigned int time, double rate){

    *Code*

    if(cb_ptr->freeSlots == 0){
        printf("\n\nEXPANDING CIRCULAR BUFFER!\n\n");
        *cb_ptr = *(expandBuffer(cb_ptr));


    }   

    *More code here edited out since it doesnt pertain to question.
}
```

and finally my main:

```
int main(){

    cbuf *cb1 ;
    cb1 = cbuf_init() ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 60, 1.291) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 63, 1.287) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 63, 1.231) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 69, 1.229) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 72, 1.247) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1,361,1.291);
    cbuf_update(cb1, 411, 1.291) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 412, 1.281) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 413, 1.292) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 414, 1.284) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 414, 1.290) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 511, 1.241) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 512, 1.251) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 513, 1.232) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 514, 1.202) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 517, 1.119) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 551, 1.080) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 552, 1.081) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 553, 1.079) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 554, 1.088) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 561, 1.072) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 562, 1.113) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 563, 1.091) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 564, 1.092) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 571, 1.089) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 572, 1.073) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 573, 1.061) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 574, 1.111) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 581, 1.119) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 582, 1.123) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 583, 1.151) ;
    return 0;
}
```

This segfaults at the line:

```
cbuf *tempBuffer = malloc(sizeof(cbuf) + newSize * sizeof(quote));
```

in expandBuffer AFTER it has already expanded once successfully. If I need to expand the buffer more than once, I get a segfault on that line.

However, if I comment out:

```
    free(cb_ptr);
```

I no longer get segfaults. However, cb_ptr (the "old" buffer being replaced by the new, larger buffer) MUST be freed since it is no longer in use. I am confused as to why freeing this up and returning a new, larger buffer to cb_ptr in cbuf_update would cause segfaults.

Comment: This seems like a typical case where making a SMALL COMPLETE COMPILABLE EXAMPLE of your problem is highly beneficial. Having a hundred lines of "cbuf_update" is probably not needed for us to understand the problem. (My bet is that you are overwriting something that you didn't intend to overwrite)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use realloc?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this:

```
*cb_ptr = *(expandBuffer(cb_ptr));
```

In the `expandBuffer` you free the pointer, but then you dereference the now free'd pointer in the assignment. This causes undefined behavior, which can (and in your case definitely) lead to a crash.

---

I suggest you instead pass the pointer by reference (i.e. a pointer to the pointer) to the `cbuf_update` function:

```
void cbuf_update(cbuf **cb_ptr, unsigned int time, double rate)
{
    /* ... */

    if((*cb_ptr)->freeSlots == 0)
    {
        printf("\n\nEXPANDING CIRCULAR BUFFER!\n\n");
        *cb_ptr = expandBuffer(*cb_ptr);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Call the new function with the address-of operator for the pointer:

```
cbuf_update(&cb1, 60, 1.291) ;
```

Comment: Since `expandBuffer` returns the pointer to the newly allocated area, `cb_ptr = expandBuffer(cb_ptr);` seems the better way.

Comment: when I try cb_ptr = expandBuffer(cb_ptr), there isn't a crash, but the data in the buffer is incorrect. if I do not free cb_ptr and keep *cb_ptr = *expandbuffer(cb_ptr), the data is correct, but it segfaults (I can view the data in valgrind, although valgrind isn't helping me pinpoint this issue). Also @joachim Pileborg, I cannot change the function prototype

Comment: @DanielFischer Not possible since it seems that the pointer needs to be updated even outside the function.

Comment: @user1806716 When you call `expandbuffer` the you free the passed `cb_ptr` pointer. But then you use `*cb_ptr` to access the (now free) memory. That will not work.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, I have to somehow free the old cb_ptr after I replace it with the newer buffer that is returned from expandBuffer. However, I can't free it anywhere without causing segfaults. Without freeing it, valgrind spits out "18 allocs, 0 frees"

Comment: @user1806716 I've already told you in the answer how you could do it. It may look similar to what you already have but there is a subtle (but **very** important) change compared to your code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg As you said, when I called expandBuffer, I passed it the cb_ptr pointer. I free that pointer in the same function, and return a new pointer to a new buffer back to the cb_ptr pointer in cbuf_update. if I change my code from *cb_ptr = *(expandBuffer(cb_ptr)) to cb_ptr = expandBuffer(cb_ptr), I no longer get segfaults, but the data in the buffer is corrupted and incorrect.

Comment: @user1806716 I say it again, please read my answer as I have already provided a solution. It may _look_ similar to what you already have but is in fact very different.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry, I am just not seeing it. I cannot change the function prototype for this, so I cannot pass cb1 by reference with & in main. It has to remain how it is. if I try to work around it and wind up with something that doesnt segfault, I wind up with a buffer that starts at the negative max int and ends at the positive max int. Sorry if I simply do not see what you are trying to say, but thank you for your help, I'll just keep trying different solutions until something works.

Comment: @user1806716 Then the only thing I can suggest is a redesign of some sort. There is no way of reallocating without passing the pointer by reference.